# Trying to detect a shake, motionEnded is never called

Tags: objective-c, ios, shake, motion-detection

I'm trying to detect a shake in iOS6, seems every single example ever was written back in 2009 or so for iOS3, and nothing's working as it should. Here's my method:

```
- (void) motionEnded: (UIEventSubtype) motion withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) NSLog(@"Detected a shake");
}
```

I've tried what Apple suggest (making a `canBecomeFirstResponder` method that returns `YES`, and calling it), but it doesn't do anything. It's called fine, but has no impact on the shake not being recognized.

I've read some stuff about needing to create a custom version of my view, but I'd really rather not screw around with that because I didn't create the view programmatically and there are four or so of them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please have a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042420/how-to-detect-shake-motion-in-iphone#6056424

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside your viewController you have to override the method caneBecomeFirstResponder and answering yes, in viewDidAppear you have to set your viewController (self) to be the first responder. This is the code:

```
-(void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) NSLog(@"Detected a shake");
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I tried the code above on my devices: iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPad 3 and iPad 1 with IOS 5. The code above works fine on all devices.

Comment: Then something else is causing a problem here, as the motionEnded method is never called. Just trying to track down exactly what.

Comment: Turns out I needed viewDidAppear, as opposed to viewDidLoad. No idea why.

Answer (score -2):

Turns out I needed viewDidAppear, as opposed to viewDidLoad. No idea why.

Comment: You shouldn't have made another post for the answer. SHould have accepted Giuseppe's post as the correct answer!

Comment: I feel that making the distinction between viewDidLoad (which I hadn't mentioned in the original question) and viewDidAppear warranted a separate answer. Giuseppe provided a solution, but I wanted to clarify the actual problem (which was using Load over Appear).

Comment: `viewDidLoad` just pertains to the view being loaded into memory. It doesn't have to do with the view being set up, ie: being in a state where it can become the first responder.